# mysql query Insert does not work

Tags: mysql, c

I am trying to insert a field into a mysql db but it does not work.

I have tried to change around abit using just "insert into image", using an query string insteed of the string literal. 
I looked [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/MySQL-Programming-C-API.html) to try understand if syntax was different or something.

I think Iam doing it according to the [API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-query.html).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV146.jpg) my setup

From the out put i get

```
i = 1
MySQL Tables in mysql database:
images
```

here is the code.

Any ideas?

```
    /* Simple C program that connects to MySQL Database server*/
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
   int main() {
      MYSQL *conn;
      MYSQL_RES *res;
      MYSQL_ROW row;
      char *server = "localhost";
      char *user = "root";
      //set the password for mysql server here
      char *password = "********"; 
      char *database = "myDB";
      conn = mysql_init(NULL);
      if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
      {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          exit(1);
      }
      /* send SQL query */
      if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables") == 1)
      {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          exit(1);
      }
    int i = mysql_query(conn ,"INSERT INTO `myDB`.`images` (`id`, `date`, `path`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'mypath/foo/bar')");
    printf("i = %d \n", i);
      res = mysql_use_result(conn);
      /* output table name */
      printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
      while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
      {
          printf("%s \n", row[0]);
      }
      /* close connection */
      mysql_free_result(res);
      mysql_close(conn);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If only mysql library has a function to get the message error, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-error.html. By the way I thing you forgot the ";".

Comment: An `insert` query must be committed. If it is not, no insertion is executed. And it does not produce any results that could be fetched.

Comment: Can you give an example @DYZ

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commit.html

Comment: @DYZ i did not know that but since I get "i=1" as return i think the query is broken. When I read here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

They do evaluate 1 as  -"if(status){//Could not execute statement}

Comment: @Jacob So you didn't even read the doc that **you** link. "Zero for success. Nonzero if an error occurred.".

Comment: @Stargateur I interpetaded it. I got to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is the primary id and INT, it may be auto-increment. If that's the case, take out `id` from your statement.

```
INSERT INTO `myDB`.`images` (`date`, `path`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'mypath/foo/bar');
```

It would be helpful to answer the question if we knew the format of the table. This is assuming `date` is TIMESTAMP and `path` is CHAR or most likely VARCHAR.

Comment: Yed id is primary key. There is a link to a pic of tha table in the Q. Id is AI

Comment: Therefore it will be automatically given a number by the database, so it can be skipped in the INSERT. Try the statement I provided and see if that works.

Comment: Nope its the same. I get respons i = 1 and nothing changes in myDB.

Comment: mysql_query should return true or false. Perhaps change that to boolean. And a better function to use to get a numerical response would be mysql_affected_rows(). That may give you some insight too.

Answer (score 0):

confirm that your ID column is not a primary key, because primary key does not allow null columns

Comment: ID is primary. But I use AI. The query was extracted from phpmyadmin. And it worked there :s

Comment: This better suited as comment.

Answer (score 0):

I manages to get it working now. I found some examples [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) that i tried to recreate and got it working.

It is not entirely same as other query

```
      if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
  }
  if (mysql_query(conn ,"INSERT INTO images VALUES (NULL , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 'awesome')"))
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not execute query \n");
      exit(1);
  }
    int my_bool = mysql_commit(conn);

  mysql_free_result(res);
  mysql_close(conn);
return 0;
```